# Rewrite the path with .htaccess a slash?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there any way to rewrite the path that only applies to 1 slash to a new domain?

For example: apply: http://example.com/13mk63fp redirect to http://newexample.com/13mk63fp

and does not apply to links with 2 or more slashes such as:

```
http://example.com/member/login
http://example.com/admin/reg
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect a url  containing a single path segment ie `/foobar` not `/foo/bar` .